# How to automatically know the selected variable in stepAIC in R?

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, lm

After running 'stepAIC', I have following result.

```
 fit1=lm(y~ x1+x2+x3+x4+x5)
 fit2=stepAIC(fit1)
 coef=fit2$coefficients

 >coef
 >intercept, x1,  x3,  x5
       5      1,    3,   5
```

I have another forecast vector z=(z1,...,z5). Because it's part of for loop, I want to compute the forecast y automatically using 'coef %*% z'.

I could think of two ways to make it happen:
1. make the unselected coefficients of stepAIC to be 0; so instead of

```
   coef=c(5,1,3,5)
```

I have

```
   coef=c(5,1,0,3,0,5)
```

2. find the selected coefficients and find the corresponding 'z_i'.

I have no idea how to implement this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: pass it the data yo want to predict on to the `predict` method; it will pull out the correct variables (if they are named the same)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`step` method / facility returns just another `lm` object, so you can apply any generic functions, including `predict` to it.

```
predict(fit2, newdata = a.data.frame)
```

---

If the final aim is not prediction, but as your question title states, use `attr(terms(fit2), 'term.labels')`.